# how to write a edit query for a grid view

Tags: asp.net

I am using grid view to fetch data from two tables.

It has got name, quantity, required quantity and lot number as few columns. Each name has got few different lot numbers and so the same name appears more than once with different lot numbers.

Now I would like to remove the required quantity from `existing quantity`. Need to re-arrange the old lot number first and then go for new one.

can someone please suggest me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: you can show INCI Name & Trade Name once and other columns as is with different values. This can be done in Gridview_PreRender() function

Comment: Post your aspx html and code behind so we can see how you set things up.

Comment: `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` and you can set in aspx BoundField and TemplateField columns.

Comment: How could you know Lot number is old one or  new one ? is there any created date if yes than you could `select with order by lot number created date asc/des`. What does this mean **remove the required quantity from existing quantity** ,do you want to subtract required quantity from existing quantity and show it as a available Quantity?